# apache virtualhost conf file and authorizations

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

Here is my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin r0dy@r0dy.net
    ServerName mtc.r0dy.net
    ServerAlias www.mtc.r0dy.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mtc
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mtc>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/mtc/bo>
            AuthName "Restricted Area: BackOffice"
            AuthType Basic
            AuthUserFile /var/www/mtc/bo/.htpasswd
#           AuthGroupFile /dev/null
            require valid-user
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When i comment out the `<Directory /var/www/mtc/bo>` part, it doesnt ask for credentials.
When i uncomment it, if i browse to this directory, it asks for credentials and it works fine.
My problem is that is asks for credentials even if i *don't* go to the /bo/ directory, i just browse to http://mtc.r0dy.net/ and i'm blocked.
Any idea on what i did wrong ?

Comment: Exactly what lines are you commenting out and how?

Comment: <Directory /var/www/mtc/bo>
            AuthName "Restricted Area: BackOffice"
            AuthType Basic
            AuthUserFile /var/www/mtc/bo/.htpasswd
#           AuthGroupFile /dev/null
            require valid-user
    </Directory>
This is the part i comment/uncomment...

Comment: I guess it's hard to see in the comments. Instead of taking chances with the rather non-standard syntax of HTTPD config, I'd test after *completely removing* the lines, not just commenting them out. Once you do that, you might consider expanding the OP with what you tried in the process if you don't find your solution before then!

Comment: The commenting/uncommenting goes fine, i dont see what this has to do with the question... my problem is that the authentication is *also* active on the *parent* folder of the one i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem, i solved it by adding Allow directives in my directories :

```html
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                #AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mtc>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                #AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
         <Directory /var/www/mtc/bo>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AuthName "Restricted Area: BackOffice"
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /var/www/mtc/bo/.htpasswd
#               AuthGroupFile /dev/null
                require valid-user
        </Directory>
```

I don't understand why it works with the allow directives and behaves strangely without, but it works fine now. If anyone has the explaination you're welcome.